# Docker container does not find System Daemon of nordvpn after reboot

Tags: docker, containers, vpn

A nordvpn subscription is not required to reproduce this problem.

Problem: Docker container does not find System Daemon of nordvpn after restart

Steps:
1 - Build (Dockerfile below) docker container with `docker build -t nordvpn .`

2 - Create and run container `docker run -it --name nordvpn nordvpn`

3 - Type `nordvpn status` to see the connection status (nordvpn is running and working here)

4 - Exit container and start it again `docker start -ia nordvpn`

5 - Type `nordvpn status` to see the error: `Cannot reach System Daemon.`

What I expected to happen: The container starts normally and connects to the VPN

What happens: Cannot reach System Daemon

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y transmission-daemon && \
    apt-get install -y wget iputils-ping curl && \
    wget -O /tmp/nordrepo.deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb && \
    apt-get install -y /tmp/nordrepo.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nordvpn=3.17.1 && \
    apt-get remove -y wget nordvpn-release && \
    rm /tmp/nordrepo.deb && \
    apt-get clean

RUN ulimit -l unlimited

ENTRYPOINT /etc/init.d/nordvpn start && sleep 5 && /bin/bash -c "$@"
CMD bash
```

Any ideas of workarounds? I've tried to run with --privileged and --cap-add=NET_ADMIN, but no luck.

Comment: Docker containers don't normally run `systemd` or other multiprocess init systems.  Rather than using an init script, a better practice is usually to set the container's `CMD` to run the single process you need to run in the foreground.  Since Docker heavily manages containers' network environments, a VPN client in a container could be a tricky setup; configuring this doesn't really seem like a programming-related problem.